# Building a multi-level nested structure via joins in BigQuery (using nested and repeated fields)

Tags: sql, json, struct, nested, google-bigquery

I have a number of flat tables in BigQuery and I want to join them into a single table which leverages nested and repeated fields at different levels (three here, but potentially more levels in future).

I have been able to do this for a single level as per the techniques in the docs/videos but I cannot seem to get the syntax right for multiple levels.

```
#dummy data to demonstrate hierarchy (travellers->cities->places)

WITH 
travellers AS (
SELECT 'Jim' as traveller, 'England' as country UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jim' as traveller, 'Spain' as country UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jill' as traveller, 'France' as country),

cities AS (
SELECT 'England' as country, 'London' as city UNION ALL
SELECT 'England' as country, 'Liverpool' as city UNION ALL
SELECT 'England' as country, 'Manchester' as city  UNION ALL
SELECT 'France' as country, 'Paris' as city UNION ALL
SELECT 'France' as country, 'Nantes' as city UNION ALL
SELECT 'France' as country, 'Marseille' as city  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Spain' as country, 'Granada' as city UNION ALL
SELECT 'Spain' as country, 'Barcelona' as city UNION ALL
SELECT 'Spain' as country, 'Madrid' as city),

places AS (
SELECT 'London' as city, 'Buckingham Palace' as place UNION ALL
SELECT 'London' as city, 'Tooting Bec Lido' as place UNION ALL
SELECT 'Liverpool' as city, 'The Liver Building' as place  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Manchester' as city, 'Old Trafford' as place UNION ALL
SELECT 'Paris' as city, 'Notre Dame' as place UNION ALL
SELECT 'Paris' as city, 'Louvre' as place  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Nantes' as city, 'La Machine' as place UNION ALL
SELECT 'Marseille' as city, 'Le Stade' as place UNION ALL
SELECT 'Granada' as city, 'Alhambra' as place UNION ALL
SELECT 'Granada' as city, 'El Bar de Fede' as place UNION ALL
SELECT 'Barcelona' as city, 'Camp Nou' as place UNION ALL
SELECT 'Madrid' as city, 'Sofia Reina' as place UNION ALL
SELECT 'Madrid' as city, 'El Bar de Edu' as place UNION ALL
SELECT 'Barcelona' as city, 'La Playa' as place UNION ALL
SELECT 'Granada' as city, 'Cafe Andarax' as place),

# full table using typical join (not what I wnat)
full_array_flat as (SELECT * FROM travellers LEFT JOIN cities USING(country) LEFT JOIN places USING(city)),

# simple nesting at a single level (using STRUCT as I will need multiple levels in future, and will need to include additional fields of different types)
travellers_nested AS (SELECT traveller, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT (country)) as country_array FROM travellers GROUP BY traveller),
cities_nested AS (SELECT country, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT (city)) as city_array FROM cities GROUP BY country),
places_nested AS (SELECT city, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT (place)) as place_array FROM places GROUP BY city),

# flattening nested arrays just for fun (!)... trying to test out different combinations
travellers_nested_flattened AS (SELECT traveller, country_flat from travellers_nested, UNNEST(country_array) as country_flat),
cities_nested_flattened AS (SELECT country, city_flat from cities_nested, UNNEST(city_array) as city_flat),
places_nested_flattened AS (SELECT city, place_flat from places_nested, UNNEST(place_array) as place_flat)

# SELECT * FROM travellers_cities_places 
SELECT "WHY OH WHY CAN'T I FIGURE THIS OUT, PLEASE HELP ME SOMEBODY!)" AS cry_for_help
```

JSON representation of the expected output is e.g.

```
[
  {
    "traveller": "Jim",
    "country_array": [
      {
        "country": "England",
        "city_array": [
          {
            "city": "London",
            "place_array": [
              {
                "place": "Buckingham Palace"
              },
              {
                "place": "Tooting Bec Lido"
              }
            ] ...
```

However no combination of ARRAY, STRUCT, UNNESTing or JOINing seems to get me to anything like this output... please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build-up the structure that you want, one aggregation at a time.

Then convert the result to a string:

```
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(STRUCT(traveller,
                             ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(country, city_array)) as country_array
                            )
                     )
FROM (SELECT traveller, country,
             ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(city, place_array)) as city_array
      FROM (SELECT t.traveller, t.country, c.city, ARRAY_AGG(p.place) as place_array
            FROM travellers t JOIN
                 cities c
                 ON t.country = c.country JOIN
                 places p
                 ON c.city = p.city
            GROUP BY t.traveller, t.country, c.city
           ) tcc
      GROUP BY traveller, country
     ) tc
GROUP BY traveller;
```

Comment: Thanks so much Gordon, and also thanks for everything else... I realised that I actually own your book and it's been super-helpful to me over the past few years, so thanks! I now have the data in the structure I need, however the intention was that I could write simple queries to extract insights from the combined (multi-level) single data table I have... I am now trying to query using Standard SQL and all of the cross joins and UNNESTs are threatening to make my brain explode. Oddly enough, the query structure for Legacy SQL seems way more intuitive:

Comment: `SELECT * FROM [project-name.user_analytics_sandbox.nested_repeating_test_output] WHERE SUBSTR(data.country_array.city_array.city,1,1) = "G" AND (data.country_array.city_array.place_array.place CONTAINS ("l") ) AND data.country_array.city_array.place_array.rating >=5`

Comment: Do you think this means that using complex nested structures in BigQuery when you're intending to run complex (multi-level) queries on them is only feasible in Legacy SQL or am I missing something? My comprehension of SQL gets exponentially worse with every level of nesting I have to traverse my brain cursor to!